# should we always use sqldatasource while we are using Gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

should we always use sqldatasource while we are using Gridview in asp.net?

I am a beginner to asp.net. We can handle gridview using sqldatasource and ado.net codes with databind.Using ado.net codes makes it complex to sort,insert,edit and update the gridview,so should we always work with sqldatasource?

Comment: you can use the datatable instead, if it fits your needs. For intro you can check this link: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-DataTable-dynamically-and-bind-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx
Point to keep in mind, in above example author populating the datatable staticly, you need a DB method that will return the data table for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is not complex to sort, insert, edit or whatever you want  while using ADO.NET. Actually it gives you more flexibility when you are used to it. SQLDataSource is also a good option. But which one you need to use completely depends on the situation. Some people suggests that while using SQLDatasource, you will find the datasource name in the rendered HTML from clientside which can be reverse engineered to find useful data about your SQL server to some extend.